# Xpath: Find an element whose descendant has got a certain attribute value

Tags: xpath

I have the following elements in a web page. I would like to fetch the element with id "pmt-id-234" which has got a descendant with classname as type2.

```
<div id="cards">
    <div id="pmt-id-123" class="payments">
        <div>
            <div class="type1">Text1</div>
        <div>
    </div>

    <div id="pmt-id-234" class="payments">
        <div>
            <div class="type2">Text1</div>
        <div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Notes:

1. I don't know the highlighted part in "pmt-id-**123**", hence direct query with ID is not possible.
2. The div with class="typeX" can be nested multiple levels down.

What is tried? The below gives me two div elements.

```
'//*[@id="cards"]//*[starts-with(@id,"pmt-id-")]'
```

Now, how to fetch the div which has a descendant div with class="type2"

The following din't yield any results.

```
'//*[@id="cards"]//*[starts-with(@id,"pmt-id-")//*[contains(@class, "type2")]]'
'//*[@id="cards"]//*[starts-with(@id,"pmt-id-")][contains(@class, "type2")]'
```

Please let me know how to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd test against `div` rather than `*` if there are only `divs` there.

This XPath will select the `div` under one with an id of `cards` that has an id that starts with `pmt-id-` and also has a descendant `div` of class `type2`:

```
'//div[@id="cards"]//div[starts-with(@id,"pmt-id-") and .//div[contains(@class, "type2"]]'
```

Note that you may have to take extra care with the matching against the @class to avoid matching `type22` or `abctype2` if such types are possible.

Comment: Thanks @kjhughes, that works! And yes, they are not all divs.